# В MyCompany в справочнике Номенклатура отсутствуют кнопки добавить Товар и Услуга

Tags: lsfusion

[image: Баг с кнопками]

В справочнике Номенклатура кнопок добавить записи нет

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Добрый день! Добавьте хотя бы одну категорию номенклатуры и сможете добавлять товары и услуги. https://mycompany-docs.lsfusion.org/Categories/